# Find closet string in java

Tags: java

I am trying to find strings from one text file that are present in another. I have 2 text files, **file1.txt** and **file2.txt** the contents of which are as below :

**file1.txt**

```
Hello
Second Line
Text line
Final Line
```

**file2.txt**

```
Final Linee
Text llline
line 3 of file2
Helloo
```

The code I have is as below :

```
public class Regex {
public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader inputFile= new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file1.txt"));

    String line;
    String pattern;

    while((line = inputFile.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(line);
        BufferedReader patternsFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file2.txt"));
        while ((pattern = patternsFile.readLine()) != null){

            Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
            System.out.println(r);

            Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

            if (m.find()){
                System.out.println("Line corresponding to pattern in file1.txt : " + line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, the above code returns all the lines from **file1.txt** that match *some* pattern from **file2.txt**. However, I want to find the closest string with edit distance of ***n*** letters. So for example if ***n=1***, then the output should be :

```
Hello
Final Line
```

and if ***n=2*** then it should output

```
Hello
Final Line
Text line
```

I am starting out with Java, and have absolutely no experience with it. Therefore any and all help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I think this problem can be solved using levenshtein distance where levenshtein is **n** as mentioned above. I am not restricting myself to RegEx, any other algorithm that might be useful would work. As `Snix` mentioned below I could use cosine distance would not be that easy to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, i can give two tips.

- First of all, you may want to look at [Apache Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/) if you are writing a text analyser or something similar or you need some strong matching features.
- Secondly, if you are looking for something more "minimal" you can implement a [Cosine Similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) algorithm which is really interesting and should really look at it.
  Then you can re-implement it and adapt for you code.
  You can find an implementation in [Apache Common Text](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/)

Comment: I have downloaded and imported the apcahe.commons jar file containing the `LevenshteinDistance` Class but cannot call it in my code. How do I use it? Any idea

Comment: Yes, `LevenshteinDistance.getDefaultInstance().apply(str1, str2);`
It's a singleton class, you are not supposed to make an instance on it :D

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out, though it was confusing as the website I used *DID* create an instance of it. I deleted my comment about 2 hours ago but I guess it wasn't deleted. Anywas thanks for the help. Though I have to say IT WAS A HUGE PAIN IN THE ASS to use Apache Lucene as I could not find the jar files or import it. Python is SOOOO MUCH easier for me to use that it was really Frustrating for me. But an unique experience none the less :)

Comment: @SteviG Glad to have been of help! Feel free to accept my answer if you feel it was useful to you. :-)